# How to schedule query in GCP BQ to update file (sheet) in a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a dataset in BQ with 4 tables.

I scheduled a query to run every week and collect new data for last 7 days and append it to the 4 tables mentioned above.

I am looking for the way of filling the updated data from these 4 tables into 4 CSV files and upload them to replace the old version weekly in a Google Storage Bucket.

Please help if you know how to automate this process to run after the successful execution of the scheduled query!

---

### Update: using EXPORT command in SQL

My issue is now to get this to run every week as when I re-run this code below I get an error that the file can't be deleted!

[image: when I re-run this code below I get an error]

I tried now with the EXPORT command and it worked, (I used "SELECT DISTINCT" and "LIMIT" to avoid getting multible files issue, my query is as follows:

```
    # Create new date variables to query last 7 days each time!
    DECLARE DateFrom STRING DEFAULT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY));
    DECLARE DateTo STRING DEFAULT FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));



    EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
    uri='gs://bucket_x_product_information/Weekly/test_*.csv',
    format='CSV',
    overwrite=true,
    header=false,
    field_delimiter=',') AS



    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `ga-data-xyz.Data.OnlineOrders` WHERE FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo LIMIT 999999
```

Best,
Naz

Comment: I don't think the storage objects are mutable upon finalization. You might need to drop the old one and create a new one (with appended information).

Comment: Ok, how to do that automatically then, I want this to be a scheduled process not a manual one!

Comment: As an option - do you think you might be able to use an 'EXPORT DATA' statement - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement

Comment: Yes, I actually started checking on that but it keeps creating many files in the bucket, as it requires a wildcard in the name, and I tried "Distinct" or "Limit" but it didn't fix the issue, do you know why would that happen?

Comment: It actually worked now, but still the issue of re-running this without getting the overwrite error, I have admin access on this bucket, what else would I need to be able to schedule this code weekly and get old file to be replaced!? @al-dann

Comment: I am  not sure I understand what the exact problem you are trying to solve, but "When you export data to a Cloud Storage bucket configured with a retention policy, BigQuery might fail to write the files to the bucket." - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations Thus, you might need to modify the policies. Or use different policies for development vs production.

Comment: True! that was the problem, and it is solved now when I reduce policy to 1 sec for testing, awesome help, thank you so much!